# relatively compact sequence in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Suppose $u_n$ is a sequence in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that
> $$u_n\geq0 \ \ \text{in} \ \ \mathbb{R}^N \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \
>  \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}u_n\,dx=\lambda$$ where $\lambda>0$ is fixed .
> Suppose also that there is a subsequence $u_{n_k}$ satisfying : there exists $y_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
> $u_{n_k}(.+y_k)$ is tight , i.e. $$\forall \varepsilon>0 \ , \
>  \exists R>0 \ \text{such that} \
>  \int_{y_k+B_R}u_{n_k}(x)\,dx\geq\lambda-\varepsilon$$ Then prove
> that $u_n$ is relatively compact in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$ .

I tried to manipulate using the condition below $$\begin{align*}&\int_{y_k+B_R}u_{n_k}(x)\,dx\geq\lambda-\varepsilon\\&\implies\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\{|.-y_k|\geq R\}}u_{n_k}(x)\,dx\geq\lambda-\varepsilon\\&\implies\int_{|.-y_k|\geq R}u_{n_k}(x)\,dx\leq\varepsilon\end{align*}$$ Then how to proceed ? Any help is appreciated .

Comment: This is false. Hypothesis is only on a  subsequence. How can you prove that the whole sequence is relatively compact?

Comment: Perhaps you should assume that every subsequence of $u_n$ contains a subsequence satisfying  $\forall \ldots$